# Map lookup function with fold

Tags: haskell, fold

I would like to create a "map lookup" function using folds.

This is my "map" (just a list of tuples):

```
phoneBook:: [([Char], [Char])]
phoneBook = [("bob", "00-21-55")
            ,("jack", "55-51-55")
            ,("joe", "10-61-25")
            ,("susy", "06-21-55")
            ,("clara", "50-31-95")
            ]
```

And this is the kind of function I would like to write:

```
lookUp :: (Eq k) => k -> [(k,v)] -> v
lookUp k = foldl1 (\acc (x,y) -> if k == y then y else acc)
```

However, this does not compile, it yields a "cannot construct infinite type" error.

Could you explain to my why this is wrong and how I can make it work?

Please note that I am aware of Data.Map and the map functions it exports, I want to do it like this solely to learn how folds work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first here is a *working* version - I'll come back and explain in a few minutes:

```
lookUp :: (Eq k) => k -> [(k,v)] -> Maybe v
lookUp k = foldl (\ acc (k',v) -> if k == k' then Just v else acc) Nothing
```

The problems you have are:

- for `foldl1` you have as type `foldl1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a` so your need the same type for your elements and your result - but here you want the value as result but fold over tuples of key/value-pairs.
- this is why I switched to the more general `foldl` (note that I am not interested in if this is the right choice here - see `foldl'` vs `foldl` vs `foldr`)
- this function can never be total (if the key is not in the dictionary/key-value-pair-list) so I opted to reflect this in the result type, which is now `Maybe v` - of course this makes it really easy to find a initial value: `Nothing`

if you don't like the `Maybe` part you can use `error` instead like this too:

```
lookUp :: (Eq k) => k -> [(k,v)] -> v
lookUp k = foldl (\ acc (k',v) -> if k == k' then v else acc) (error "key not found")
```

### Remarks:

this is not the most efficient implementation as you will look through all of your list no matter if you found the key yet - feel free to try to come up with something that does

**hint**: Haskell is lazy - maybe you can find something by filtering out the right key/value-pairs, taking the safe-head of this and then maping to the value-part ;) )

Comment: Can we all take a moment to admire how wonderfully well-formatted this answer is?

Comment: @AJFarmar the wonders of markdown ;) (it's not really hard to do - but thanks)